# Is there any simple software available which can display the current outgoing sound levels?

Tags: windows-10, audio

Short and sweet, I'm trying to compare the levels of two different sounds' output when running through a game. Code-wise the game shows that they're being played at the same level as well as the sound files themselves being levelled equally. However with a rough estimation using Windows 10's "Volume Mixer" I can see they're different.

Essentially, I just want to be able to see/map what the output sound level is at for a given time, graphing would be even better but I'm not holding my breath.

Windows 10 volume mixer is not accurate enough for me to gauge the differences between the sounds outside a rough estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some opensource projects like VU METERS here, I think this will work for  you:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/windowsvumeter/?source=directory
https://sourceforge.net/projects/vu-meter/?source=directory

[[image: Default State[1]]
[image: User Selected Color]